# Allowing htmlspecialchars to render UTF-8 chars, while still escaping regular tags

Tags: php, html, utf-8, htmlspecialchars, html-sanitizing

I'm using htmlspecialchars to escape user input that is rendered on the page (so that a user input of `If you want bold text, wrap it around a <b> tag like <b>this</b>` actually renders out that way, instead of interpreting the `<b>` as actual html and bolding the `tag like this` text.

htmlspecialchars works great here, but seems to incorrectly render UTF8 chars as the htmlentity number code. E.g. the look of disapproval `ಠ_ಠ` renders as `&#3232;_&#3232;` after going through the function.

What should I be doing to properly escape regular html, but still allow users to use special UTF8 chars?

Comment: `&#3232;_&#3232;` should render on the page as `ಠ_ಠ` the same way that `&gt;` will render as `>`, whether it's in a paragraph tag, an input box, a textarea... are you saying that you simply don't want these conversions to take place? What issue is this causing you? Short of using str_replace on a set of characters that you specify (painful), or some funky regex, there isn't really an easy way of selectively encoding characters. It's all or nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: The `&#3232;_&#3232;` is rendering as both `&#3232;_&#3232;` in the html and on-screen. Perhaps I'm missing something else on my page that should be rendering out those html entities as characters.

Comment: Hmm... would you be able to put up a test page somewhere? Or dump the html here or to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the right encoding?

Is it possible the utf8 characters have been converted to the notation of ಠ? If you call htmlspecialchars again on that string the & becomes an & and therefor is not a utf8 code anymore, this can be prevented by setting the double-encode parameter to false. See the documentation on php.net:

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars